# JavaFX dialog fill a table in another view

Tags: dialog, javafx, javafx-8

I've view that contains a table and a button. The button opens a dialog (another view) with a few text fields and a button.

How can I add the data entered in the dialog's text fields to the table in the first window (the window that called the dialog).

```
main.fxml.MainController
dialog.fxml.DialogController
```

I've tried to set the table (TableView) in the main window to public static, but I still get the `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I can add data to the table, but only from the same window where the table is.

Br,

Klaus

Comment: You should look for solutions that share the data between controllers, not the view (e.g. the table). Then your question simply becomes "How do I pass data to another controller", which is addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/14190310#14190310

Comment: Thanx James, so if I understod you correctly I should use a model for this. I've created a model "Person", so no my question is how should I add data to the model in the dialog and use it to add data to the TableView.

Comment: The model for the table is basically the items list.